# How to Display dropbox folder images to asp.net C# datalist

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to show Dropbox image to asp.net datalist control what i have tried is under

```
RequestResult strReq = OAuthUtility.Get
(
    "https://api.dropbox.com/1/metadata/auto/",
    new HttpParameterCollection
    {
        { "path", "FilePath" },
        { "access_token", "AccessToken" }
    }
);
```

Datalist Code

```
<td>
    <asp:Image ID="Image2" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# Eval("Image")) %>' Width="220px" Height="140px" />
</td>
```

this code is not working .anybody help me

Comment: What is exactly not working? Where do you set source of this image?

Comment: The source of image is at FilePath.